problem with fetch.then not completing before response data expected from .then being used in JavaScript
I'm working on a small webapp using  nodeJS and express. Client-side  script includes the following:
let firstList = []
 
fetch(`${baseUrl}canList`, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((jsonResponse) => {
        firstList = jsonResponse
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
    })
})

after fetching data for a second list,  The script sets up  event listeners for a text input field and a button. Next,  I'm trying to use the content of the firstList in the following function:
function start() {
    listBox.innerText = ''
    listContainer = document.createElement('div')
    listContainer.classList.add('text-container')
    listBox.append(listContainer)  
    firstList.forEach(el => {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.innerText = el
        document.querySelector('.text-container').appendChild(div)
    })
    addstyle()

}
start()

My problem is that the .then( response)...  handler has not executed to  populate  the firstList  array.   instead the .then only starts executing after running through the client script.  So the start  function iterates over an empty array
otherwise, everything works just fine after this, . The button is used to switch between presenting the first list and second list  using a CSS text animation. and the input text field can be used to and an element to be currently displayed list, which is posted back to the node express app and appended to the file  accessed using the fetch  operations. However,because the start function runs before the array is  populated  neither list is displayed until the button is clicked.
I've tried wrapping the fetch in an async function and then using await as well as writing the fetch .then chain without using the arrow function. I only started learning JavaScript/ node/CSS about a month ago, so  please forgive my awkward description

fetch() is asynchronous. Code running after it doesn't wait for the .then() functions to complete. Put the call to start() in the last .then()

@Barmar Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that.   Probably because I'm just learning. It's too bad the question was closed. already seen  some of what is referenced by the close message, as well as a pile of other question/responses.  I asked the question because the reference material wasn't helping me solve the problem..   but not because I hadn't bothered to look at it. So, again, thank you.  that was the help I was looking for

Edit the question to show how you tried to apply the advice there, and request that it be reopened. Then we can answer and show how to do it correctly.

Basically: .then((jsonResponse) => { firstList = jsonResponse; start(); })
